# Why my recyclerView android is empty. My DataSet comes from my API. Is it a sync problem?

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview, synchronization, android-volley

I am new in android and I would like to show in my recycler view my dataSet when the activity starts, but when I execute my app and start the activity, the recyclerview is empty.

[image: onCreate]

[image: get Categories]

[image: result]

But if I call `notifyDataSetChanged()` method on my add button's click listener (onCreate method) it "works" (if I click the button).

[image: notyfyDataSetChanged]

[image: result 2]

So... The problemen is not getCategories or the adapter (I guess).

Someone knows how to solve it?
Thanks!!

Comment: Instead of attaching the images of the code please paste it in your question, using the markdown formatting for the code. Regarding your question, yes it seems to be a sync problem, be sure to pass the list to your adapter only once it's populated.

Comment: Did you solved?

Answer (score 0):

Well, you are using Volley to get data from an API. When you call the `list = getCategories()` then it will fetch the data in the background. So, `adapt = new CategoryAdapter(list,this)` will execute immediately without waiting to get response from **getCategories();**. Eventually, you will get an empty list.

However, you are getting data when you call **notifyDataSetChanged()** because that time your background process may be finished and your list will be not empty.

**Solution:** Add **notifyDataSetChanged()** in onResponse() in for loop.